# SQL Trigger Recursive update

Tags: sql, triggers

I have an organizational database where in it each employee have a foreign key to it's boss(FID).

Table declaration:

```
Create Table Emp(
    ID  integer,
    FID integer,
    SALARY integer,
    Primary key (ID), 
    foreign key (FID) references EMP
);
```

The following sql trigger should update the employees under a boss. And then update their children recursively. but it only updates one level.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAL_TRIG ON EMP After UPDATE
as
declare @SALARY int  
declare @OLDSAL int 
declare @ID int      

--use the 'inserted' keyword to access the values inserted into the invoice table
select @OLDSAL = Salary from deleted
select @SALARY = Salary from inserted 
select @ID = ID from inserted


BEGIN
    UPDATE EMP 
    SET SALARY = salary + @SALARY - @OLDSAL
    WHERE FID = @ID
END
```

I want to know how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server, you need to enable recursive triggers using sp_dboption. See MSDN for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx